# Sphinx search SQl to get exact word

Tags: sql, sphinx

My keywords column in table looks like

`dog,dogs,dog and cat,dogs and cats`

It's a commas separated words

I have try to get exact word now and query like this one is back me result but is not what I need and actually they match all this but I just need to get post ID where is `dog,` in this example.

`SELECT id FROM {$CONF['sphinx_index']} WHERE MATCH('@keywords ",dog" | ",dog," | "dog,"')`

In sql this should be easy `WHERE (keywords LIKE 'dog,%' OR keywords LIKE '%,dog,%' OR keywords LIKE '%,dog')` but for sphinx I can't find solution, anyone have idea how to make query for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CONCAT('_sep_ ',REPLACE(REPLACE(keywords,' ','_space_'),',',' _sep_ '),' _sep_') AS keywords
```

And than search "`_sep_ dog _sep_`" to match *dog* or "`_sep_ dogs_space_cats _sep_`" for *dogs and cats*

Answer (score 0):

You could just add comma to `charset_table` which would mean it indexed as part of words. But would also need to enable infix or prefix matching to be able to match part words, ie `dog,dogs,dogs` would index as one word.

An alternative might be to turn spaces into say underscores (already in charset_table) and index each tag as a word

```
dog dogs dogs_and_cats dog_and_cat
```

Sort of thing. Can just match world tags as words